# Find the max from each row in Python

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

How to find the max from each row in Python and store it in a NumPy array or Pandas DataFrame and store it in a NumPy array, i.e. the output below?

```
0.511474    0.488526
0.468783    0.531217
0.35111     0.64889
0.594834    0.405166
```

Output:

```
0.511474
0.531217
0.64889
0.594834
```

Comment: are the rows lists, df etc?

Comment: `df.max(axis=1).values`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `numpy amax` function. [np.amax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.511474,    0.488526],
            [0.468783,    0.531217],
            [0.35111,     0.64889],
            [0.594834,    0.405166]])
# axis=1 to find max from each row
x = np.amax(a, axis=1)
print(x)
```

which returns:

```
[0.511474 0.531217 0.64889  0.594834]
```